# Break A Number Up To An Array of Individual Digits

Tags: swift

If I have the integer 123 and I want to break the digits into an array [1,2,3] what is the best way of doing this?  I have messed around with this a lot and I have the following working:

```
var number = 123    
var digits = Array(String(number)).map{Int(strtoul((String($0)),nil,16))}
```

I look at it and feel there might be an better/easier way of doing this.  If not then maybe it will come up on web searches.  Any alternatives ideas?

Comment: Better in what respect? Shorter, faster, ...?

Comment: I use map a lot and this works good with all numbers that I've tried.  I was wondering of other approaches to this.

Comment: I just realized that my question doesn't really match to a single answer.  But as I look through answers to other questions I don't always go with the accepted answer.  I love the alternative ideas!

Answer (score 9):

It is easier to work on the UTF-8 representation of the number string
because the UTF-8 code unit of a decimal digit can easily be converted to
the corresponding integer by subtracting a constant:

```
let asciiZero = UInt8(ascii: "0")
let digits = map(String(number).utf8) { Int($0 - asciiZero) }
```

This also turned out to be significantly faster.

If *performance* is the primary goal then you should restrict
the method to simple integer arithmetic, without using strings
or characters:

```
var digits : [Int] = []
while number > 0 {
    digits.insert(number % 10, atIndex: 0)
    number /= 10
}
```

Here is my complete test code for your convenience (compiled
with Xcode 6.4 in Release mode on a MacBook Pro).

```
func digits1(number : Int) -> [Int] {
    let digits = Array(String(number)).map{Int(strtoul((String($0)), nil, 16))}
    return digits
}

func digits2(number : Int) -> [Int] {
    // Use a static property so that the constant is initialized only once.
    struct Statics {
        static let asciiZero = UInt8(ascii: "0")
    }

    let digits = map(String(number).utf8) { Int($0 - Statics.asciiZero) }
    return digits
}

func digits3(var number : Int) -> [Int] {
    var digits : [Int] = []
    while number > 0 {
        digits.insert(number % 10, atIndex: 0)
        number /= 10
    }
    return digits
}

func measure(converter: (Int)-> [Int]) {
    let start = NSDate()
    for n in 1 ... 1_000_000 {
        let digits = converter(n)
    }
    let end = NSDate()
    println(end.timeIntervalSinceDate(start))
}

measure(digits1) // 10.5 s
measure(digits2) // 1.5 s
measure(digits3) // 0.9 s
```

---

**Update for Swift 3:**

```
func digits(_ number: Int) -> [Int] {
    var number = number
    var digits: [Int] = []
    while number > 0 {
        digits.insert(number % 10, at: 0)
        number /= 10
    }
    return digits
}

print(digits(12345678)) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

This also turned out to be slightly faster than appending the digits
to an array and reversing it at the end.

Comment: using UTF-8 code unit seems to give the speed advantage.  plus it reads well!

Comment: @pn1dude: I have added another possible solution (faster but more code).

Comment: nice use of modulus 10 and /= as a decimal shifter popper!

Comment: Works for strictly positive Ints

Comment: @ielyamani: Yes. It wasn't specified if the integer can be zero or negative, or what the intended result would be in that case. Whoever needs it should have no problems to handle these cases.

Answer (score 3):

Another Swift 3 alternative is making use of the global [`sequence(state:next:)` method](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/2011998-sequence).

**Swift 3.1**

```
let number = 123456
let array = Array(sequence(state: number,
    next: { return $0 > 0 ? ($0 % 10, $0 = $0/10).0 : nil }
    ).reversed())

print(array) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

**Swift 3.0**

```
let number = 123456
let array = Array(sequence(state: number,
    next: { (num: inout Int) -> Int? in
        return num > 0 ? (num % 10, num /= 10).0 : nil
    }).reversed())

print(array) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

---

The approach above assumes a non-negative number, and will moreover return an empty array (`[]`) is case `number` is `0`. To cover the full range of natural numbers as follows:

```
// -123 -> [1, 2, 3]
// 0    -> [0]
// 123  -> [1, 2, 3]
```

We can modify the above to:

```
// for some number ...
let number = ...

// Swift 3.1
let array: [Int]
if number == 0 { array = [0] }
else {
    array =  Array(sequence(state: abs(number),
    next: { return $0 > 0 ? ($0 % 10, $0 = $0/10).0 : nil }
    ).reversed())
}

// Swift 3.0
let array: [Int]
if number == 0 { array = [0] }
else {
    array = Array(sequence(state: number,
    next: { (num: inout Int) -> Int? in
        return num > 0 ? (num % 10, num /= 10).0 : nil
    }).reversed())
}
```

---

**Some details regarding the tuple return above**

In the single line return above, we've made use of the neat *"`()`-return operation inlined as tuple member of type `()`"*, a method that I first saw used by @MartinR in his improvement proposal to update [the following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35161029/4573247). We use the last member of a `(Int, ())` tuple to mutate the `state` property `num`; the first member of the tuple will be computed prior to the execution of the `()`-return operation in "computing" the 2nd tuple member.

We can draw an analogy between this tuple method and the approach of executing a closure with a single `defer` and `return` statement. I.e., the `return` statement:

```
return num > 0 ? (num % 10, num /= 10).0 : nil
```

*could* also be accomplished by executing such a closure instead ("long form", in this context)

```
return num > 0 ? { defer { num /= 10 }; return num % 10 }() : nil
```

I haven't benchmarked these two approaches against each other, but I have a feeling the former will be faster when repeatedly being called as in the context of `sequence(state:next:)` above.

---

**Swift 3.0 vs 3.1: anonymous argument in the `next` closure above**

Due to the now closed (Swift 3.1 and onwards) bug reported in [SR-1976](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1976) (*Closure signature in Swift 3 required for inout params*), there's a limitation in Swift's type inference for `inout` parameters to closures. See e.g. the following Q&A for details:

- [Global function sequence(state:next:) and type inference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40201844/global-function-sequencestatenext-and-type-inference)

This is the reason why we have to explicitly annotate the type of the `state` in the `next` closure of the Swift 3.0 solution above, whereas we can make use of anonymous arguments in the `next` closure for the Swift 3.1 solution.

Comment: Hey, I just was about to add that solution :)

Comment: @MartinR ah, I hope I didn't post it just as you were to update yours! Too bad we can't use anonymous arguments for the `next` closure (due to `inout` argument bug [SR-1976](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1976), i think), or it could be even neater :)

Comment: The sequence-based solution is a bit faster than the explicit loop with inserting or appending to an array. I'll add some benchmarks later.

Comment: @MartinR I didn't expect it to be on par with the explicit loop, that's nice. Thanks!

Comment: `extension BinaryInteger {
    var digits: [Self] {
        var source = self
        return sequence(state: source) { _ in
            source > 0 ? (source % 10, source /= 10).0 : nil
        }.reversed()
    }
}`

Answer (score 2):

My take for **Swift 2**:

```
var x = 123
var digits = String(x).characters.map { Int(String($0))! } // [1,2,3]
```

It is more explicit about the characters, so I think it is quite readable.

Comment: Yeah didn't notice the "Swift 2" thing...  Still back on the 6.4 playground.  I like the  way it reads for sure and I will try it once we move to 7!

Answer (score 1):

The other answers have not taken the radix into account—the example demands 16, not 10.

```swift
public extension UnsignedInteger {
  /// The digits that make up this number.
  /// - Parameter radix: The base the result will use.
  /// - Note: Leading zeros are not taken into account. Zero itself will yield an empty array.
  @inlinable func digits(radix: Self = 10) -> [Self] {
    sequence(state: self) { quotient in
      guard quotient > 0 else { return nil }

      let division = quotient.quotientAndRemainder(dividingBy: radix)
      quotient = division.quotient
      return division.remainder
    }
    .reversed()
  }
}
```

```swift
(867_5309 as UInt32).digits()
[8,6,7, 5,3,0,9]

(0xF0 as UInt8).digits(radix: 0b10)
[1,1,1,1, 0,0,0,0]

(0xA0_B1_C2_D3_E4_F5 as UInt).digits(radix: 0x10)
[10,0, 11,1, 12,2, 13,3, 14,4, 15,5]

(0o707 as UInt16).digits(radix: 0o10)
[0b111, 0, 0b111]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are new to swift but let's be clear, the method where you use the `map` is the best for what you want to do:)
There is another approach that i don't recommend cause having a good visualisation of your code structure is really important.

```
import Foundation

var number2 = 123
var number3 : String = "\(number2)"
var array : [String] = []
var str2 = ""
for i in number3.characters
{
    str2.append(i)
    var string = NSString(string: "str")
    string.doubleValue
    array.append(str2)
    str2 = ""
}
```

cheers

Comment: Been working with swift for awhile but with each new release I sometimes question how much I do know...  I use map a lot.  In the for loop "i" will by of type Character by default.

Comment: map and join are two awesome functions of swift cause you actually avoid all the trouble of doing for loops and such. really good way to keep your code clean and code faster and smarter. i suggest you have a look at closures. those things are i think one of the best swift has. Really simplify things

Comment: agreed -> map join closures! Oh my!

Answer (score -1):

I'd say if it isn't broke don't fix it. I can thing of one other way, but it's not any shorter or anything:

```
var number = 123
var digits = map(String(number)) { String($0).toInt() ?? 0 }
```

Comment: You may be correct but this reads a bit nicer!  Works fine in 6.4 playground.

Comment: Just because something is not (yet) broken is **not** a reason to not fix it. Code optimization (event for aesthetics aka readability) is always in order.