# swift maximum consecutive positive numbers

Tags: swift, closures

How to count maximum consecutive positive numbers using closures?

```
var numbers = [1,3,4,-1,-2,5,2,-2,-3,-4,5]
//in this case it should be 3

print(numbers.reduce(0, { $1 > 0 ? $0 + 1 : $0 } ))//this counts total positive numbers
```

Comment: we look for the number in numbers: 1,3,4 - all positive, we count them - its 3. then 2 negative numbers, 2 positive, 3 negative and 1 positive. So, maximum consecutive positive numbers - 3.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Update:* Simpler solution: Split the array into slices of
positive elements, and determine the maximal slice length:

```
let  numbers = [1,3,4,-1,-2,5,2,-2,-3,-4,5]
let maxConsecutive = numbers.split(whereSeparator: { $0 <= 0 }).map { $0.count }.max()!
print(maxConsecutive) // 3
```

---

*Old answer:*) Using the ideas from [Swift running sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35160890/swift-running-sum/40613935#40613935):

```
let  numbers = [1,3,4,-1,-2,5,2,-2,-3,-4,5]

let maxConsecutive = numbers.map({
    () -> (Int) -> Int in var c = 0; return { c = $0 > 0 ? c + 1 : 0; return c }
}()).max()!
```

Here `map()` maps each array element to the count of consecutive positive
numbers up to the elements position, in this case

```
[1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

The transformation is created as an "immediately evaluated
closure" to capture a variable `c` which holds the current number of
consecutive positive numbers. The transformation increments  or resets `c`,
and returns the updated value.

If the array is possibly large then change it to

```
let maxConsecutive = numbers.lazy.map( ... ).max()!
```

so that the maximum run length is determined without creating an
intermediate array.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I want - simple and short solution! How can I find average consecutive positive number? With map we get [1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1], now what to use, filter and reduce? The result should be [3,2,1], then sum 6 divide by count 3 = 2

Comment: @Anton: Inspired by your new question, I have updated this answer with a much simpler solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
var currentResult = 0
var maxResult = 0
for i in numbers {
    currentResult = i > 0 ? currentResult + 1 : 0
    if maxResult < currentResult {
       maxResult = currentResult
    }
}
print(maxResult)
```

Solution without closures

Comment: Thanks, but i need solution with closures)

Comment: print(numbers.reduce(0) { $1 > 0 ? $0 + 1 : 0 }) - this gives me 6 in this example - all positive numbers. How do I get max consecutive numbers using closures (3 in this case)?

Comment: This returns `0` for the array `[1,2,3,4]`

Comment: @MartinR oops) Updated the code) Thanks for checking)

Answer (score 2):

```
var numbers = [1, 3, 4, -1, -2, 5, 2, -2, -3, -4, 5]

let result = numbers.reduce((current: 0, max: 0)) { result, number in
    var value = result

    if number > 0 {
        value.current += 1
        value.max = max(value.current, value.max)
    } else {
        value.current = 0
    }

    return value
}



result.max
```

Comment: Good idea, but there seem to be some problems. It returns 0 for the given array.

Comment: @MartinR you're right! There was a problem but now it fixed. Cheers  :)

Answer (score 1):

Generating subsequences:

```
let numbers = [1,3,4,-1,-2,5,2,-2,-3,-4,5]
let subsequences: [[Int]] = numbers.reduce(into: []) { (result, number) in
    guard
        var currentSequence = result.last,
        let lastNumber = currentSequence.last
    else {
        result = [[number]]
        return
    }

    if number == lastNumber + 1 {
        currentSequence.append(number)
        result.removeLast()
        result.append(currentSequence)
    } else {
        result.append([number])
    }
}
let longest = subsequences.max { $0.count < $1.count }
print(subsequences)
print("Longest subsequence: \(longest)")
print("Longest length: \(longest?.count)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Detect Three consecutive number in an array

```
var  data = [1,2,5,4,56,6,7,9,6,5,4,5,1,2,5,4,56,6,7,9,8,1,1,2,5,4,56,6,7,9,8,1,1,2,5,4,56,6,7,9,8,1,1,2,5,4,56,6,7,9,8,1,1,2,5,4,56,6,7,9,8,11,2,5,4,56,6,7,9,8,1,2,3]

for i in 0...data.count{
    if i+2 < data.count{
        if Int(data[i] + data[i+2]) / 2 == data[i+1] && Int(data[i] + data[i+2]) % data[i+1] == 0 && data[i+1] != 1 && data[i] < data[i+1]{
            print(data[i] ,data[i+1], data[i+2])
        }
    }
}
```