# maximum number of consecutive in swift

Tags: swift, algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to learn Swift by solving easy interview questions on LeetCode.

Question is as follows:

Given a binary array, find the maximum number of consecutive 1s in this array.

**Example 1:**

**Input:** [1,1,0,1,1,1]

**Output:** 3

Explanation: The first two digits or the last three digits are consecutive 1s.
    The maximum number of consecutive 1s is 3.

**Note:**

The input array will only contain 0 and 1.
The length of input array is a positive integer and will not exceed 10,000

I have solved the following question, no issue, it runs and covers up test cases, but it shows my submission is only 73 percent faster than all the submissions. I wonder whether or not there is a better way to solve this question. My solution time complexity is O(n).

```
class Solution {
    func findMaxConsecutiveOnes(_ nums: [Int]) -> Int {

        var globalMax = 0
        var localMax = 0

        for num in nums
        {
           if num == 1
           {
              localMax += 1
              globalMax = max(globalMax, localMax)
           }
           else
           {
                localMax = 0
           }  
        }
        return globalMax
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47137246/swift-maximum-consecutive-positive-numbers

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ may be a better home for this question

Comment: It's not an issue here, but in general, it's better to use `isEmpty` than testing `count == 0`. It's makes the intent more explicit and if your type doesn't conform to `RandomAccessCollection`, it is actually more efficient. But as others have pointed out, that check is not necessary at all here. The more material observation is that you shouldn't call `max` every time `num == 1`...

Comment: To be honest, this is a fine solution, the complexity is the best possible. Some optimizations could be probably achieved but the overall improvement will probably be machine specific and in order of milliseconds or even lower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is more appropriate for the [Code Review site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swift). The rankings in LeetCode are not reliable and may vary from submission to the next (with the same code).

Here is a solution that avoids `if .. else` (original java code [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/max-consecutive-ones/discuss/96807/Concise-Java-Solution-without-%22if%22.))  :

```
func findMaxConsecutiveOnes4(_ nums: [Int]) -> Int {
    var globalMax = 0
    var localMax = 0

    for num in nums {
        localMax *= num
        localMax += num
        globalMax = max(globalMax, localMax)
    }
    return globalMax
}
```

For benchmarking, I've used the following code :

```
let array = (0...10_000).map { _ in Int.random(in: 0..<2) }

let start1 = mach_absolute_time()
let x1 = findMaxConsecutiveOnes1(array)
let end1 = mach_absolute_time()
print("1st", x1, Double(end1 - start1)/Double(1e3), "us")

let start2 = mach_absolute_time()
let x2 = findMaxConsecutiveOnes2(array)
let end2 = mach_absolute_time()
print("2nd", x2, Double(end2 - start2)/Double(1e3), "us")

let start3 = mach_absolute_time()
let x3 = findMaxConsecutiveOnes3(array)
let end3 = mach_absolute_time()
print("3rd", x3, Double(end3 - start3)/Double(1e3), "us")
```

Where `findMaxConsecutiveOnes` is your solution, `findMaxConsecutiveOnes2` is [Joakim's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53888408/2907715), and `findMaxConsecutiveOnes3` is the one proposed in this answer.

Compiled with optimizations (`-O`) in the terminal, here are the execution times:

- findMaxConsecutiveOnes1 : `49.079 us`
- findMaxConsecutiveOnes2 : `54.016 us`
- findMaxConsecutiveOnes3 : `14.883 us`

---

## Faster than 100.00% of Swift online submissions (For now)

[image: 312]

The following implementation is considered the current fastest by LeetCode :

```
func findMaxConsecutiveOnes(_ nums: [Int]) -> Int {

    guard !nums.isEmpty else {
        return 0
    }

    var globalMax = 0
    var localMax = -1

    for i in 0..<nums.count {
        if nums[i] != 1 { //It is faster than: if nums[i] == 0
            localMax = i
        }
        globalMax = max(globalMax, i - localMax)
    }
    return globalMax
}
```

[Here](https://leetcode.com/problems/max-consecutive-ones/discuss/145941/Easy-C%2B%2B-Solution-Using-Two-Pointers-(O(n)-beats-99.57)) is the original C++ implementation.

In my benchmarks, it didn't perform as expected : **`33.615 us`** on a 10,000 element array.

**But**, on smaller sized arrays, it proved to be **the quickest solution**.

---

## Even faster solution

[image: 308]

This is the fastest :

```
func findMaxConsecutiveOnes(_ nums: [Int]) -> Int {

    guard !nums.isEmpty else {
        return 0
    }

    var globalMax = 0
    var lastZeroIdx = -1

    for i in 0..<nums.count {
        if nums[i] == 0 {
            globalMax = max(lastZeroIdx == -1 ? i : i - lastZeroIdx - 1, globalMax)
            lastZeroIdx = i
        }
    }
    globalMax = max(lastZeroIdx == -1 ? nums.count : nums.count - lastZeroIdx - 1, globalMax)
    return globalMax
}
```

It was ported from [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/max-consecutive-ones/discuss/207730/java-solution-using-zero-Index-instead-of-count.) java implementation.

In my benchmarks, I couldn't notice any improvement in execution time on neither small (10-element) nor big (10,000-element -> `42.363 us`) arrays .

Comment: It is interesting, equal to 0 and not equal to 1 operation! why does it improve performance?

Comment: @hotspring The inequality operator `!=` is faster than `==` on some architectures.

Answer (score 2):

Two minor adjustments, checking array size isn't really necessary and calling max only needs to be done when a 0 is found and at the end

```
func findMaxConsecutiveOnes(_ nums: [Int]) -> Int {
    var globalMax = 0
    var localMax = 0

    for num in nums {
       if num == 1 {
          localMax += 1              
       } else {
            globalMax = max(globalMax, localMax)
            localMax = 0
       }  
    }
    return max(globalMax, localMax)
}
```

I did an experiment with split and reduce and this combo seems slightly faster than the one above but about the same as the one linked to in the comments

```
func findMaxConsecutiveOnes3(_ nums: [Int]) -> Int {
    return nums.split(separator: 0).reduce(ArraySlice<Int>(), { ($1.count > $0.count) ?  $1 : $0 }).count
}
```

Comment: I dislike the `reduce` solution because `lazy.map { $0.count }.max ?? 0` would be much more readable.

Comment: Obviously, `max()`, not just `max`.

Comment: @Rob either way, in my tests with optimizations (`-O`) in the terminal, the functional approach is **five** times as slow as the iterative one. The array used in my benchmarks is the following `let array = (0...10_000).map { _ in Int.random(in: 0..<2) }.shuffled()`.

Comment: @Carpsen90 - Interesting, because on my computer it is only 25% slower. But I wasn't trying to argue that functional was more performant than other approaches, but rather only suggesting possible refinements to the functional pattern that was proposed by Joakim and Sulthan (much like I might wonder why you'd bother shuffling an array of random values, lol). Personally, unless the performance is observable and material, that's not what dictates my choice to use functional patterns or not.

Comment: @Rob Sorry for being a little late in responding here, the idea of using `omittingEmptySubsequences` is great but now that I've had time to read the documentation I see that the parameter defaults to `true` so without knowing I've already taking advantage of this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps they expect some Swift-specific tricks.

If not - I could suppose that checking system dislikes calculations at every 1-item.

You can calculate global max only in case of 1-0 transition (or at the end of array). In this case you also need to remember index of 1 in case of 0-1 change.