# Int array to Int standard method

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, int, swift3

I am trying to convert an `Int` array to an `Int` number. What I am now
doing is converting it to a `String` array and then use the `joined()` function. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Example:

```
let sortedIntArray = String(number).characters.map{Int(String($0)) ?? 0}.sorted(by: { $0 > $1 })

let desOrder =  Int(sortedIntArray.map{String($0)}.joined())!
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your case, `sortedIntArray` is an array of *single-digit* numbers,
and then you can combine them without any conversion to strings:

```
let sortedIntArray = [4, 2, 1]
let result = sortedIntArray.reduce(0) { 10 * $0 + $1 }
print(result) // 421
```

Combined with the [dfri's elegant solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40737068/1187415) to split the number
into an integer array:

```
let number = 1439

let descDigits = sequence(state: number, next: { (num: inout Int) -> Int? in
    return num > 0 ? (num % 10, num /= 10).0 : nil
}).sorted(by: >)
print(descDigits) // [9, 4, 3, 1]

let descNumber = descDigits.reduce(0) { 10 * $0 + $1 }
print(descNumber) // 9431
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the reduce method instead of map and joined

```
let desOrder = Int(sortedIntArray.reduce("") { $0 + String($1) })
```

`reduce(intialResult: Result, (Result, Any) throws -> Result) rethrows`

Answer (score 1):

You asked about efficiency, as to [this answer by Martin R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32488173/5099208), my guess is that is the most efficient answer

```
var number = 1992843
var arr = [Int]()

while number > 0 {
    arr.append(number % 10)
    number = number / 10
}

arr.sort() 
arr.reverse()

for n in arr {
    number = number * 10
    number += n
}
```